# Customize the clone textarea content jQuery

Tags: jquery, clone

I wonder if it is possible to customize the cloned contents of a textarea.

For example if I copy and paste content of numbers:

```
5412565139972
5412561706239
5412564338352
5412558764488
5412563782224
```

I generate the same information but with some additional elements such as:

```
http://www.domain.com/5412565139972.ph3
http://www.domain.com/5412561706239.ph3
http://www.domain.com/5412564338352.ph3
http://www.domain.com/5412558764488.ph3
http://www.domain.com/5412563782224.ph3
```

It is possible in jquery?

Comment: sure, it's possible. try it, see what you come up with. come back when you have a question involving the code.

Comment: to point you to the right direction, you will prob need regExp to sort though the content of a textarea, to extract the information you need. put them in a array than out put the desired result.

Comment: You could show me an example, please?